# What does slot mean in vue's render function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In vue, there is a slot option in render function, the document says "slot is the name of the slot, if this component is the child of another component". I can not understand what it means. My understanding is that the slot name is the node returned by createElement function's name as a slot, but it seems wrong. My English is poor, I am sorry if I didn't describe the question clearly.

```js
Vue.component('render-component', {
  render(h) {
    return h('div', {
      class: 'main'
    }, [
      h('div', { slot: 'header' }, 'header'),
      h('div', { slot: 'footer' }, 'footer')
    ])
  }
})

let vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      message: 123
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <render-component>
    <template v-slot:header>111111</template>
  </render-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Vue’s introduction to slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) to understand what a slot is. The example you are looking at is a shorthand using a render function to render an array of named slots. It is roughly equivalent to this code from the docs:

```
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <slot name="header"></slot>
  </header>
  <main>
    <slot></slot>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <slot name="footer"></slot>
  </footer>
</div>
```

A named slot allows you to specify multiple slots within a component (without a name it merely defaults). Everything within the relevant `<template>` element for the slot will then be passed to the slots, e.g.:

```
    <template v-slot:header>
    <h1>Here might be a page title</h1>
  </template>
```

Comment: But if you run the code above, the '111111' in template does not replace the slot named 'header' in the render function.

Comment: I think that's not what OP's asked for. He meant, what is the second argument of `createElement('div', { slot: 'slot-name' }, 'contents')` mean, not what the SLOT is at all in Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Option `slot` means that result of render function will be inserted into slot of component that was used in first param.

```js
Vue.component('card-component', {
  template: `
<div>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <strong><slot/></strong>
  <i><slot name="note" /></i>
</div>
  `
});

Vue.component('parent-component', {
  render(h) {
    const defaultSlotContent = h('p', {}, 'default description');
    const namedSlotContent = h('p', {slot: 'note'}, 'It is a note')
    return h('card-component', {}, [defaultSlotContent, namedSlotContent]);
  }
});

let vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      message: 123
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <parent-component />
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `it is a note` would be rendered as a children, not inside a slot.